# Cannot post a tweet using rest assured

Tags: rest-assured, web-api-testing

I cannot post a tweet using Rest assured, the test case passes every time but the status code is 403. I have passed the consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken and secretToken. I have attached a screenshot.[pleaseCheckAttached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Hjl.png)

Comment: The test case passed b/c you didn't assert anything. 403 means you're authenticated but has no rights to access/ do this action. It's really hard to help this kind of problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the queryParameter here. Please refer [this github page](https://github.com/TanmoyNandy/RestAssuredWithTwitterAPI/blob/master/RestAssuredWithTwitterAPI/src/test/java/testCases/Tests.java) for the complete code to post a tweet.

It should be something like below

```
PostATweetPOJO postATweet = given().auth()
                .oauth(consumerAPIKey, consumerAPIsecretKey, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
                .queryParam("status", postATweetData.getStatus()).when().post(Resources.getPostATweetResource()).then()
                .extract().response().as(PostATweetPOJO.class);
```